# ASPxGridView update command trigger via postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview, updatecommand

I have a gridview with showeditbutton and shownewbutton enabled. How can i trigger post back on the page whenever a new row is added/updated ? Is there
any properties similar to autopostback that can apply in gridviewcommand ? Thanks in advance.

Asp.net

```
 <dx:ASPxGridView ID="FollowUpGrid" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ClientInstanceName="FollowUpGrid" KeyFieldName="sno" DataSourceID="gridsource">                  
      <Columns>
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn CellStyle-ForeColor="White" ShowNewButtonInHeader="true" ShowEditButton="true" VisibleIndex="1" >
</dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

vb.net

```
 gridsource.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE tablename set something = something
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to completely switch ASPxGridView to a postback mode (for all triggers/actions/operations) by settings the **ASPxGridView.EnableCallBacks** property to False ([Why might control updating and creating not work on a callback of another control](https://www.devexpress.com/kbid=KA18609)).

If you need to receive a notification and updated an external content, use the approach illustrated here [here](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/aspxgridview-how-to-update-an-external-control-during-a-callback-e2379).